Calculating beam waist of a Gaussian beam
+I am trying to calculate the beam waist $w_0$ of a Gaussian laser beam of $\lambda$ = 1030$\,$nm that we have ordered from a supplier. However, on the technical data sheet, we have only been provided the BPP of 2 mm.mrad. This laser also passes through some focusing optics with $f$ = 400$\,mm$ and the numerical aperture NA of the output optical fiber is 0.1. Now I would like to try and find $w_0$, but I am concerned that we do not have any information on the divergence angle of the beam, so calculating $w_0$ from BPP cannot be done easily. In addition, the NA only provides the maximum possible output angle (in this case, about 6°), which is far too large for a laser beam.
The datasheet referenced is from this supplier (https://www.trumpf.com/en_US/products/lasers/disk-lasers/trudisk/)
Is it possible to calculate $w_0$ for such a system with the information provided? What additional information, if any is required?

What makes you say 6° is "far too large for a laser beam"? Diode lasers can commonly emit beams with 30° divergence. Free-space coupled fiber lasers will have output divergence determined by the NA of the fiber used, if no collimating optics are provided.

That said, if you've put up the money to buy one of these things, there should be a Trumpf application engineer available to answer your questions.

You have the focal length of the focusing optics. The output of this is a more strongly converging Gaussian beam. https://www.rp-photonics.com/numerical_aperture.html
